# What does this function do in Facebook's JavaScript source?

Tags: javascript

I was reading some of Facebook's JavaScript, and came across a curious function that I couldn't figure out the purpose of:

```
function bagof(a) {
    return function () {
        return a;
    };
}
```

*As far as I can tell*:

- `bagof` is a function that accepts the parameter `a`.
- `bagof` immediately returns an anonymous function.
- The returned function then returns the original parameter `a`.

I would assume that the usage of `bagof` would be something like this:

```
newFunction = bagof("This is the data");
​console.log( newFunction() );​ //Logs "This is the data"​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What's the point? Why not directly use or store whatever variable or function that was passed into `a`?

[The source file](http://jsbin.com/upuken/edit#javascript) looks like it contains many utility functions for the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bagof()` method can be used as a factory creating constant functions (functions always returning the same value).

Even if you use in such a context:

```
var randomFun = bagof(Math.random());
```

Invocation of `randomFun()` will always return the same value because `Math.random()` is evaluated only once (eagerly). I guess it is utility method used when some API requires a method and we simply want to pass constant value. Instead of:

```
giveMeCallback(function() {return 42})
```

you can simply say:

```
giveMeCallback(bagof(42))
```

Comment: So, the function doesn't really "do" something, but serves as shorthand for creating other function easily?

Comment: @MichaelJasper: no, it has no side-effects and does not compute anything. Its sole purpose is creating functions, think about [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)